# Number of edges of isomorphic graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

This is an easy question, but I find it so easy that I think something in my reasoning must be wrong since it is really simple:

> Given a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices such that $G$ is isomorphic to $G^c$ (complementary graph, $G^c = K_n \backslash G $), find the number of edges of $G$

Since $G \simeq G^c$, they must have the same number of edges, this is, $|E(G)| = |E(G^c)|$. Since $|E(G^c)| = |E(K_n)| - |E(G)|$ and $|E(K_n)| = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} = {n \choose 2}$, then $|E(G)| = {n \choose 2} - |E(G)|$, then $|E(G)| = \frac{n(n-1)}{4}$. Here, $|E(G)|$ denotes the number of edges of $G$ and $K_n$ is the complete graph of $n$ vertices. Is this right?

Comment: That is pretty correct. Such graphs are called self-complementary. (In your question it says "find the number of vertices". That will be $n$. I assume you meant number of edges after all)

Comment: Sorry, edges I meant

Comment: It looks perfect.

Comment: Your reasoning is indeed correct. I’d point out that there’s a sense in which your expression, namely $\frac{n(n-1)}{4}$, isn’t the best *form* for the answer. If you expressed your (correct) answer instead as ${n \choose 2}/2$, that would not only tell what the answer is, but also give a fairly strong suggestion of *why* that answer is correct. You could think of it as a self-documenting answer.